# IndexOutOfBoundsException in search for

Tags: java

i have a problem that return me the follow error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at graphsshahar.TestDijkstra.main(TestDijkstra.java:38)
```

my program get a list of objects and i need to find in the list the equal to one 
and then print it , here is the code

```
    public static void main (String [] args){
    System.out.println("begin");

    int one = 2;
    int two = 10;
    List<Conniction> tempDeal = ConnictionDAO.getInstance().findPath(one, two);

    List<String> oneid = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> twoid = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int j = 1; j <= tempDeal.size(); j++) {
     System.out.println("get");
        if( Integer.parseInt(tempDeal.get(j).getOneid()) == one ) 
        {
            oneid.add(tempDeal.get(j).getOneid());
            System.out.println(oneid.get(j));

        }

    }
    System.out.println("end");
```

what should i fix ?
i dont know what is wrong with the if statement

Comment: Your variable names for :
int one = 2;
int two = 10;
are very misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Just change yours with this `j < tempDeal.size()` Numbering starts from 0 not from 1.

```
for (int j = 0; j < tempDeal.size(); j++) { ... }
```

If you would use `j = 1` you are not able to get item at 0 position.

**Update:**
You can use also iterator like meant @AVD.

```
for(Conniction member: tempDeal) {
   // do work
}
```

Comment: He also needs to change `int j = 1` to `int j = 0`, because, as you noted, indexes start at 0.

Comment: @Julien that's in the "Numbering starts from 0 not from 1".

Comment: alternatively if theres a reason he specifically needs the for loop starting at 1 then all uses of j when accessing the list need to be j-1

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry, but I really don't see how leaving out the correction of the second problem in that line ameliorates the answer. If anything, it makes it more confusing.

Comment: @Julien maybe OP needs to search from `j = 1` and not from `j = 0`, also check the title: IndexOutOfBoundsException, if you array has at least 2 elemens, array[1] woudln't raise up that exception but the `j <= tempDeal.size()` will. That's why `j = 0` is a hint to improve the code, not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int j = 1; j < tempDeal.size(); j++)
```

If it is not intentional, 'j' should start from '0'

```
for (int j = 0; j < tempDeal.size(); j++)
```

List index starts with '0'

Comment: The problem is the `j <= tempDeal.size()`. The answer should point to that, the index start is another hint.

Answer (score 2):

If *index* isn't matter then you may use iterator `for` loop.

```
for(Conniction obj: tempDeal){
    if(obj!=null) {
       if(Integer.parseInt(obj.getOneid())==one){
            oneid.add(obj.getOneid());
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
for (int j = 0; j < tempDeal.size(); j++) {
```

Lists indexes starts at 0 and ends at size() - 1

Comment: You're not explaining why OP should change the code, and the name of the variables should be a comment, maybe is just a test, so let it be.

Comment: @Luiggi even if it is just test code naming them one and two is still bad.  It is still possible to come up with suitable names in test code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Right, not enough explanations at first. As you said the second part (variable names) is just a remark, but I'll leave it because those names are really misleading.

Comment: @JonTaylor as I've posted, the name of the variables should be a comment, not part of the answer, changing the variable names won't solve OP's problem, just improve the readability (another hint).

Comment: Calm down, I just removed this remark to put it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you need different counter for the `oneid` array. If the if-statement return false once, the next time you enter here you'll get IndexOutOfBounds.

```
int oneIdCount = 0;
```

and increment it inside the `if`

```
if( Integer.parseInt(tempDeal.get(j).getOneid()) == one ) 
    {
        oneid.add(tempDeal.get(j).getOneid());
        System.out.println(oneid.get(oneIdCount));
        oneIdCount++;
    }
```

and as the above answers - start the for from `int j=0`

And if you want to print the last element only you can use `oneid.size()-1` instead of variables.